# Atomic increment if non-negative and atomic decrement if non-positive

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I have two groups of threads A and B. Threads in A execute function `funA`, and threads in B execute function `funB`. It is OK for threads in each group to execute their functions concurrently, but `funA` and `funB` must not be executed concurrently. How do we achieve this? Is this problem have a name, so I can read about it online?

One possible solution is the following:

```
std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter{};
void funA() {
  std::int64_t curr = 0;
  while( 
    (curr=counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) < 0 ||
    !counter.compare_exchange_weak(curr,curr+1,std::memory_order_relaxed));
  // implementation of funA goes here
  counter.fetch_sub(1); // better to happen using RAII
}
void funB() {
  std::int64_t curr = 0;
  while( 
    (curr=counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) > 0 ||
    !counter.compare_exchange_weak(curr,curr-1,std::memory_order_relaxed));
  // implementation of funB goes here
  counter.fetch_add(1); // better to happen using RAII
}
```

Is this correct? Is it the best we can do? What I don't like about it is that threads in same group compete against each other on those while loops.

Comment: You may like to issue [`pause`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=pause&expand=4141) instruction before retrying `counter.load`.

Comment: I wonder why concurrent invocations of one function don't race with its own parallel invocation, but do race with concurrent invocations of another function?

Comment: This is what I came up with to represent my own problem in a short and easy to understand question. An easy example for your equation is multiple read single write (multiple reads are ok). But of course, this is more complicated. We can imagine `funA` and `funB` access the same external device such that concurrent invocation of each function is OK, but `funA` and `funB` must NOT be be run concurrently. The only difference is that, in my problem, everything happens in the main memory/CPU, so performance is very important (otherwise, lock-based approach would be used).

Comment: Is there a cross-platform library that implements `pause`? or does nothing if that functionality is not available in the machine the code is compiled on?

Comment: I'd rather you described your real problem than a "representation" of it.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. You are working on your project, and if it is a small one, it takes a couple of thousands of lines of code. Then you have a problem. I see no point in talking about the project and where the problem is in it. In fact, if I see one of those, the first thing that I would ask is to separate the problem, simplify it, write a minimal code that exhibits the problem. In this example, I thought about it for a day to find how I can represent the problem best.